# How to find a list of files and zip them into a single zip file?

Tags: find

I want to collect all the files I have used in a project. I am using `find` command, and I want it to find a list of files and then I pass its result to zip command to create a single zip file containing all the matched files. Just a convenience if it is possible. However, it seems there are problems with it and it does not work.

```
find /lmms/samples/ -name warp01*,JR_effect2k*,clean_low_key*,q_kick_2*,sticky_q_kick*,upright_bass*,pizzi*,chorded_perc*,Tr77_kick*,Tr77_tom1*,Tr77_cym*,hihat_008a*,Hat_o.ds,Hat_c.ds,Kickhard.ds,Tr77_snare* -exec zip {} ~/Desktop/files.zip
```

Output is:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

PS.

After fixing some errors pointed out in the below answers and following their guidelines, I have reformatted the code as below:

```
find ~/lmms/samples/ (-name warp01* -o -name JR_effect2k* -or -name clean_low_key* -or -name q_kick_2* -or -name sticky_q_kick* -or -name upright_bass*-or  -name pizzi* -or -name chorded_perc* -or -name Tr77_kick* -or -name Tr77_tom1* -or -name Tr77_cym* -or -name hihat_008a* -or -name Hat_o.ds -or -name Hat_c.ds -or -name Kickhard.ds -or  -name Tr77_snare*)  -exec zip -add  ~/Desktop/files.zip {} +
```

It still fails with the message `bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('
`

Removing the parentheses eliminates error but does seem to only add one file to the archive, which surprisingly, I do not seem to find on my Desktop!!!

```
 find ~/lmms/samples/ -name warp01* -o -name JR_effect2k* -or -name clean_low_key* -or -name q_kick_2* -or -name sticky_q_kick* -or -name upright_bass*-or  -name pizzi* -or -name chorded_perc* -or -name Tr77_kick* -or -name Tr77_tom1* -or -name Tr77_cym* -or -name hihat_008a* -or -name Hat_o.ds -or -name Hat_c.ds -or -name Kickhard.ds -or  -name Tr77_snare*  -exec zip  ~/Desktop/files.zip {} +
  adding: home/john/lmms/samples/drumsynth/tr77/Tr77_snare.ds (deflated 49%)
```

Comment: Following your PS: there still remain several errors in your `find` command (proper spacing and  pattern quoting). I have updated my answer to add a zip-only command.

Comment: You **need** to quote the patterns as StephenKitt showed you in his answer: `-name "file*"`, not just `-name file*`

Comment: I think It actually worked without quoting after I escaped the parentheses.

Comment: Sometimes it will work, sometimes not, and you probably won't notice it. You are free to not follow Stephen's syntax of course.

Comment: @xhienne then would not that require escaping double quotations used around file names? Sorry to ask,  just too tired to test it for now :(

Comment: Every pattern (i.e. filename containing `*`, `?` or `[...]`) should be surrounded be single or double quotes: `-name clean_low_key*` => `-name 'clean_low_key*'` or `-name "clean_low_key*"`. See the note in my answer. If you want a clear demonstration of why it matters, do `shopt -s nullglob` and try your command (then undo this with `shopt -u nullglob`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-exec` takes two parameters: the command to execute, and a flag to tell `find` whether the command should be run once per match (`;`) or with as many files as possible per run (`+`).

In addition, the `zip` parameters are the wrong way round.

The `-name` test doesn't work that way either; it only takes one pattern at a time. If you want to check for multiple patterns, you need to use multiple `-name` tests combined using `-o` ("or"), and wrap them in parentheses (thanks to [xhienne](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/203203/xhienne) for pointing that out):

```
find /lmms/samples/ \( -name "warp01*" -o -name "JR_effect2k*" ... \) -exec ...
```

(quoting each pattern to avoid issues with shell globbing).

All in all, if you fix your name tests and end your `find` with

```
-exec zip ~/Desktop/files.zip {} +
```

it should do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt it seems to work now. Files have been added to ~/Desktop/files.zip, but in hierarchical order. I mean their directories have been added as well. Here is the created zip if you mind checking it out. http://s9.picofile.com/file/8282171700/files.zip.html

Comment: If you don't want to store the paths, you can use `zip`'s `-j` option to drop them. You need to be sure that you don't have two (or more) files with the same name in different directories!

Answer (score 5):

You just need to terminate your `-exec` option with either a `;` or a `+` (`man find`). Your `zip` file must precede the files you put in your archive IIRC, so this would become:

```
find ... -exec zip ~/Desktop/files.zip {} ;
find ... -exec zip ~/Desktop/files.zip {} +
```

The `+` version aggregates the parameters at the end of the `zip` command and calls one `zip` for all the files (or several `zip` if your commands are really long). It's less I/O intensive but the downside is that you can only use `{}` once and at the end, just before the `+`. The `;` version is more flexible but calls `zip` for each file.

#### Alternate solution without find

You also have a problem with the `-name` predicate and @StephenKitt gives you the correct syntax.

Here is another syntax that uses `zip`'s ability to understand globbing patterns like `file*`. Therefore it doesn't use `find`, is closer to your original proposal, and probably less error-prone for someone not used to `find`:

```
$ zip -r  ~/Desktop/files.zip /lmms/samples/ --include 'warp01*' 'JR_effect2k*' 'clean_low_key*' 'q_kick_2*' 'sticky_q_kick*' 'upright_bass*' 'pizzi*' 'chorded_perc*' 'Tr77_kick*' 'Tr77_tom1*' 'Tr77_cym*' 'hihat_008a*' 'Hat_o.ds' 'Hat_c.ds' 'Kickhard.ds' 'Tr77_snare*'
```

Note: patterns are separated by space. The quotes around them are mandatory, else the patterns may be interpreted by your shell, not by `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

For performance and "White Space" reasons I strongly recommend using `-print0 | xargs -r0`, e.g.

```shell
find /foo/bar -xdev -type f -mtime -2 -print0 | xargs -r0 zip "$HOME/foo-bar.zip"
```

In your case it should look like

```shell
find /lmms/samples/ -name warp01*,JR_effect2k*,clean_low_key*,q_kick_2*,sticky_q_kick*,upright_bass*,pizzi*,chorded_perc*,Tr77_kick*,Tr77_tom1*,Tr77_cym*,hihat_008a*,Hat_o.ds,Hat_c.ds,Kickhard.ds,Tr77_snare* -print0 | xargs -r0 zip ~/Desktop/files.zip
```